# In proof of the Proposition 11.3. in the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading the John Lee's Introduction to Riemannian manifolds, proof of proposition 11.3. and stuck at some statement. I think that it is first time to see this kind of pattern (?) ..

> **Proposition 11.3.** Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold, $U\subseteq M$ is a normal neighborhood of $p\in M$, and $r$ is the radial distance function on $U$. Then $g$ has constant sectional curvature $c$ on $U$ if and only if the following formula holds at all points of $U - \{p\}$ :
> $$ \mathcal{H}_r = \frac{s_c'(r)}{s_c(r)}\pi_r, \tag{11.6}$$
> where $s_c$ is defined by $(10.8)$, and for each $q\in U-\{p\}$, $\pi_r : T_qM \to T_qM$ is the orthogonal projection onto the tangent space of the level set of $r$ (equivalently, onto the orthogonal complement of $\partial|_q$).

*Proof.* $ \Rightarrow)$ (Omitted..) We accept this direction.

$ \Leftarrow)$ Conversely, suppose $\mathcal{H}_r$ is given by $(11.6)$. Let $\gamma$ be a radial geodesic starting at $p$, and let $J$ be a normal Jacobi field along $\gamma$ that vanishes at $t=0$. By Proposition 11.2, $D_tJ(t) = \mathcal{H}_rJ(t)=s_c'(t)J(t)/s_c(t)$. A straightforward computation then shows that $s_c(t)^{-1}J(t)$ is parallel along $\gamma$. **Thus we can write every such Jacobi field in the form $J(t)=ks_c(t)E(t)$ for some constant $k$ and some parallel unit normal vector field $E$ along $\gamma$.** Proceeding exactly as in the proof of Theorem $10.14$, we conclude that $g$ is given by formula $(10.17)$ in these coordinates, and therefore has constant sectional curvature $c$. **QED.**

If needed, I will upload more information about involving notations, theorems etc.. more in detail. I don't understand the bold statement. How can we find such constant $k$ and parallel unit normal $E$ along $\gamma$? It seems like it could work, but I'm not sure how can we find that precisely

Can anyone help?

Comment: The question should be more focused, such as: Assume that $f(t)^{-1}J(t)$ is a parallel vector field along $\gamma$, then why does there exists a constant $k \geqslant 0$ and a unit parallel vector field $E(t)$ such that $J(t) = k f(t) E(t)$? The whole setting here brings unnecessary notations ($H_r$, $\pi_r$, etc.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing out ~  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector field $V(t) = s_c(t)^{-1}J(t)$ satisfies $D_t V(t) = 0$ (this is the definition of being parallel along the underlying geodesic).
In particular, it has constant norm: indeed, $\frac{d}{dt}\|V(t)\|^2 = 2 \langle D_tV(t),V(t)\rangle = 0$.
Let $k = \|V(t)\|\geqslant 0$ be this constant, and assume that $k >0$.
Define $E(t) = \frac{1}{k}V(t)$, which is then a unit vector field, parallel along the underlying geodesic.
Then by definition, $V(t) = kE(t)$.
This is still true if $k = 0$.
Hence, $J(t) = ks_c(t)E(t)$ for some constant $k \geqslant 0$ and $E(t)$ unit parallel vector field along the underlying geodesic.

Comment: Wow. O.K. It seems like an easier statement to prove than I think. I learned a lot. Thank you !